# initialization with python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization

I have a problem with correct initialization within a list

```
import random

a = [random.randint(0,1) for x in range(10)] # getting random 0 and 1

b = a[:] # copying 'a' list for purpose of analysis 

for x,y in enumerate(b): # adding + 1 where value is 1
    if y != 0:
        b[x] += b[x-1]



print(a) # > [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]  
print(b) # > [2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2]
# wanted # > [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

from a[1:] everything is ok. Python does correct initialization, however if a[0] == 1 and a[9] == 1, Python ofcourse takes a[9] as a start value in my case.

I am just asking if there is any pythonic way to solve this > explaining python to just start initialization from 0 at a[0] and passing a[9] as first value.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  Your code produces the output I would expect it to, and I think it lines up with your explanation of what you want.  Could you clarify what exactly is wrong, and provide what you expect the output to be?

Comment: Please check the code again. I added the wanted result.

Comment: Change the if condition to - `if y!=0 and x!=0`

Comment: :D Great solution thank you.

Comment: I like hashcode55's solution. The problem is that `b[0-1]` references the last item in the list, which could be a 1.

Comment: This is a simple property of python's negative indexing. If you only want to start your addition from index 1, just start it from index 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the first value rather easily:

```
for x,y in enumerate(b[1:]): # adding + 1 where value is 1
    if y != 0:
        b[x + 1] += b[x]
```

`b[1:]` just skips the first value from the list for the enumeration. This way the first number is untouched. But because the indexes in `x` are now all one too low, we have to add one in both cases, turning `x` into `x + 1` and `x - 1` into `x`. This way we access the right index.

Using your test list, it produced the following output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]  # original list
[1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2]  # processed list
```